# FireFox Com Function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, firefox

For IE microsoft provides COM to access it programatically. Is there any function to access Firefox from our Program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mozilla Active X Control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm) has largely compatible interface. (IWebBrowser/IWebBrowser2/...)

Of course Native XPCOM interfaces are a possibility for C++ programs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a way to have your program that isn't running in Firefox to be able to access Firefox API's?  If so, the answer is no.